# Perl .bundle files

Tags: perl, cpan, xml-libxml, cpanm

On my OSX machine, deep within a jungle of lib directories, I was able to see this

`-r-xr-xr-x 1 user users  45700 Feb 01 1:47 LibXSLT.bundle*`

1) What are these .bundle files ?

2) Who creates them ? CPAN modules ?

3) If so, then can we control its generation via some Makefile artifact ?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/67249/what-is-a-bundle-file-and-how-do-i-run-it - doesn't seem to be Perl specific.

Comment: I am specifically looking for .bundle files related to Perl CPAN.

Comment: These file may be related to this module: [XML::LibXSLT](http://search.cpan.org/~shlomif/XML-LibXSLT-1.94/LibXSLT.pm)

Comment: Yes it gets install during installation of above module. Discussion on [Perlmonk](http://www.perlmonks.org/bare/?node_id=528106).

Comment: @AbhiNickz That discussion is about module tests crashing, not .bundle files.

Comment: @melpomene Yes, Correct but as OP has asked **Who creates them ? CPAN modules ?** that's why I gave that link.

Comment: OK, the relevant command is `LD_RUN_PATH="/sw/lib:/usr/lib" MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.3 cc  -bundle -undefined dynamic_lookup -L/usr/local/lib LibXSLT.o perl-libxml-mm.o  -o blib/arch/auto/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle   -L/sw/lib -lxslt -lexslt -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm`, which looks like it creates a shared library / application plug-in, as described in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bundle_(macOS)#macOS_loadable_bundles.

Comment: Seems to be specific to OS/X. `cc` (`gcc`) on Linux doesn't recognize `-bundle`.

Comment: [About Bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html)

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What are these `.bundle` files ?

The `*.bundle` files, in this case, are [Mach-O universal binary files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O).

`file` can be used to check the file type including architectures.

```sh
file …/Perl/…/XML/LibXSLT/LibXSLT.bundle
# /LibXSLT.bundle: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: 
#    [x86_64:Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64] 
#    [arm64e:Mach-O 64-bit bundle arm64e]
```

> 2. Who creates them ? CPAN modules ?

[`lipo` is the tool used for combining one or more architecture specific executables](https://ss64.com/osx/lipo.html) into a *Mach-O universal binary*. (In general, although Perl may need the extension, the `.bundle` file extension is optional.)

```sh
which -a lipo
# /usr/bin/lipo

man lipo
# NAME
#        lipo - create or operate on universal files
```

> 3. If so, then can we control its generation via some `Makefile` artifact ?

The Apple article ["Building a Universal macOS Binary"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/apple-silicon/building-a-universal-macos-binary) mentions how to use a (C/C++/Swift) `makefile` to create a universal binary by merging the resulting executable files together with the `lipo` tool.

> The following example shows a makefile that compiles a single-source file twice—once for each architecture. It then creates a universal binary by merging the resulting executable files together with the `lipo` tool.

```makefile
x86_app: main.c
    $(CC) main.c -o x86_app -target x86_64-apple-macos10.12
arm_app: main.c
    $(CC) main.c -o arm_app -target arm64-apple-macos11
universal_app: x86_app arm_app
    lipo -create -output universal_app x86_app arm_app
```

Conceptually, the above approach could be used with a `ExtUtils::MakeMaker` `Makefile.PL`.